# Sticky button in GWT

Tags: user-interface, gwt, button

can i create a button in gwt that onClick stays pressed and if it looks pressed onClick releases it?
and the button has a different styles in each state?

any idea?

Comment: So you want the appearance of the button to toggle between pressed and released?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That sounds like a [ToggleButton](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ToggleButton.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty basic approach that should give you the toggle that you want. Basically the first click will put a 'clicked style' that you've created that will give the thing the look you want for when it looks pressed. Clicking it a second time will revert back to your normal button style so it will look not pressed again.

```
final Button button = new Button();
button.setStyleName("NormalButtonStyle");
button.addClickHandler( new ClickHandler() {
  private boolean clickedStyle = false;
  public void onClick( final ClickEvent clickEvent ){
    clickedStyle = !clickedStyle;
    if( clickedStyle ){
      button.setStyleName("ClickedButtonStyle");
    }
    else {
      button.setStyleName("NormalButtonStyle");
    }
  }
});
```